# Display JSON text in freemarker

Tags: javascript, json, freemarker

JSON text:

[{"desc":null,"amount":250,"item":"527"},{"desc":"test","amount":3333.33,"item":"522"},{"desc":null,"amount":3333.33,"item":"522"},{"desc":null,"amount":1500,"item":"520"},{"desc":null,"amount":1560,"item":"519"}]

I tried the following Code but it is not working:
<#assign customrecord = record.custpage_custrecord_itemlist?eval />
<#list customrecord as customrecord_line>

<#list customrecord as customrecord_line>

```
${customrecord_line.item}
${customrecord_line.desc}
${customrecord_line.amount}

</#list>
```

Note:(record.custpage_custrecord_itemlist is the variable that contains the json text)
Please help

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to parse JSON inside a template? I saw people trying to do this all the time on SO. What's the use case for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Since 2.3.31 there's `?eval_json` for this. Not only it understands JSON `null`, but also it's safer, as it can't call the methods of the objects in the data-model (because it's not evaluated as FTL, just as JSON).

There's no JSON parser built into the template language. `?eval` parses FTL expressions, not JSON. The two happens to be similar, but not identical. Unlike in JSON, in FTL there's no `null`. So I guess the error you run into is that `null` is undefined. A possible workaround is that you do something like `<#assign null=''>` earlier, so when `?eval` sees `null`, it replaces it with an empty string (which is not very good, but you see what the mechanism is; you could chose some other special value as well).

But the only correct solution would be using a real JSON parser and put the result into the data-model (or to write a `TemplateMethodModel` that does calls a real JSON parser and returns the result).

Comment: thanks a lot! that answers my question. I'm really new to freemarker